# Issue: Why Restore database wizard/GUI for SQL Server 2014 loading old backup set to restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms

I am using SQL server 2014 to restore backups using the GUI, however, the back sets to restore are from old backups that are no longer available along with transaction logs that span months ago.

How can I repair the wizard so that it populates the most recent full and diffs and transaction logs like the way it used to work by default?

Here is a sample screenshot of the of the restore database screen I am making reference to
[image]

Comment: I started answering misunderstanding - but now I'm a bit more confused. Can you post a bit more details? What happens if you restore via script? And are you talking about what's in backup history? Or what happens when you look at a particular backup file and explore what it contains?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the screens where it shows what database backups you can restore, and also if you have 'appended' backups which will put multiple backups in 1 file?

Comment: @MikeWalsh In the area where it says backup set to restore from I get old backups.

Comment: You need to purge the backup history of backups that no longer exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wizard is really just a listing of backup history records in MSDB on that local server. This wizard is not necessary to do backups. In fact, you should run a process to purge backup history on a regular basis. When I do a SQL Server Health Check for a client, I consider it a finding (relatively minor but still a finding) when this history is purged.

I am wondering if you are attempting to restore to a different server which also has that database on it?

Instead, choose Device and browse to your backup file. You'll see the right backupset to restore to inside of that backup file.

The dialog here is sort of a helper if you are restoring on the same server where your SQL Agent backups are taken but if you take backups in different ways, if you clean up history or if you are restoring to a different server, that dialog is likely not so helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I get that I can backup using other option. However, the transaction logs can become overwhelming when to script out and in my case, they are taken every 10 mins. Therefore I would use the GUI to script out those many trans logs and apply them on other server or said server. I it may seem minor but if i could somehow repair the GUI to work as it is supposed to that was make my life soooo much easier.

Comment: Simple question - are you restoring to the same server the backups are taken from or a different server? If a different server - the GUI isn't broken at all.

You might try and do the restore dialog process on the source server and then script it out but don't run and copy/tweak. Also there are myriad scripts out there. I have many clients with frequent log backups and I don't know that I've ever used the GUI to restore those...

Comment: Yes it was the same server. The syspurge policy job was broken and fixing that helped the situation. I know this is late and the matter was years ago but felt like saying what was the cause thanks